# Stored Procedure stopped working

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I'm positive of has no errors but I recently deleted the table it references but imported a backup with the same name exactly and same column settings (including identity) that the previous one had but now it doesn't work.

Is there any reason that having deleted the table but importing a new would break the stored procedure?

BTW: Running Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition w/ IIS.

Comment: And the stored procedure looks like?  And the error message is?  You gotta throw us a bone here

Comment: I've +1'd both @Jim B's comment @gbn's comment ... you *really* need to give more information to get a good answer from us ... the error message you're being given when running the stored procedure is a good start =)

Comment: Yea no error message. The page that catches the info just didn't display the data on the formview control because nothing was getting inserted. I was positive nothing is wrong with the stored procedure because I had just used it. I just needed to recompile is all. 

Thanks All.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to recompile the stored procedure with:

```
exec sp_recompile YourProblemTableNameHere
```

this will recompile all procedures that use the `YourProblemTableNameHere` table.  But that is just a guess based on the very limited info given.

Comment: Thanks Perfect. You're my new God (big G).